# Django celery and main app on one core cpu vps server?

Tags: django, redis, celery, vps

I'm new in celery. Can I run Django celery and main app on **one core cpu vps** server? I need to update information at the website each hour from a queue which I will keep in Radis cache. And also I need make some calculations(not so hard but it takes time) in background, result of each I want put to queue.
The question is, will I able to do it all on the single core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. Obviously you won't get as high performance as running everything on separate machines, but for a reasonably low-traffic site there will be no problem.